# python schemdraw AttributeError: __enter__

Tags: python

```
import schemdraw
import schemdraw.elements as elm

with schemdraw.Drawing() as drawing:
    drawing.config(unit=2)
    drawing += (L1 := elm.Line().right())
    drawing += (L2 := elm.Line().right())
    drawing += (C := elm.Capacitor().down().label('C'))
    drawing += (L3 := elm.Line().Left())
    drawing += (L4 := elm.Line().left())
    drawing += (R := elm.Resistor().endpoints(L1.end, L3.end).label('R').idot())

    drawing.draw()

    drawing.save('scheme.png')
```

Wanted to write a simple script for a circuit, but I always get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/Lukas/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 4, in 
> with schemdraw.Drawing() as drawing:
> AttributeError: **enter**
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

does anyone have a idea what can be wrong?

Comment: How did you install `schemdraw`?

Comment: What version is it?

Comment: For what it's worth, I do not encounter this error. The code executes correctly, other than the typo of `Left` instead of `left` and that the output is actually svg. Do you get the error if you run exactly the code you showed us?

Answer (score 4):

`schemdraw` didn't add the context manager until the most recent version. You can find the commit [here](https://bitbucket.org/cdelker/schemdraw/commits/cf037b9d31f2d0114cff41d5a05b83458e6d0277).

Unless you installed version `0.14` which was released on January 9, 2022, you won't have access to the context manager.

You can see version [`0.13`](https://pypi.org/project/schemdraw/0.13/) examples do not utilize it.

```
import schemdraw
import schemdraw.elements as elm
d = schemdraw.Drawing()
d += elm.Resistor().label('100KΩ')
d += elm.Capacitor().down().label('0.1μF', loc='bottom')
d += elm.Line().left()
d += elm.Ground()
d += elm.SourceV().up().label('10V'))
d.draw()
d.save('schematic.svg')
```

But the [`0.14`](https://pypi.org/project/schemdraw/0.14/) examples do.

```
import schemdraw
import schemdraw.elements as elm
with schemdraw.Drawing(file='schematic.svg') as d:
    d += elm.Resistor().label('100KΩ')
    d += elm.Capacitor().down().label('0.1μF', loc='bottom')
    d += elm.Line().left()
    d += elm.Ground()
    d += elm.SourceV().up().label('10V')
```

Comment: So I installed the 0.14 Version of Schemdraw for Python 3.9 and my python interpreter is also set to Python 3.9, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same exact error? With your code I get an `AttributeError` on this line 
 `drawing += (L3 := elm.Line().Left())` but that's because `Left` is a typo and should be `left`. After correcting that it runs without errors.

Comment: yes I'm gettin the same exact error. maybe I have multiple versions of python 3.9 and use the 'wrong' one